# Kotlin/Java processBuilder efficiency vs python subprocesses

Tags: java, python, kotlin, process, subprocess

I'm having trouble with JVM processes, I'm trying to create a program which needs to call a different language program with changing parameters each times, a lot of times.

For example, lets say I need to call node.js program via my main program (KotlinJvm) 1000 times in 10 seconds.

Now, I'm using ProcessBuilder class in order to create a new process so I can get the information back to my main, but its not fast enough. its even slow :/

I researched a bit and found out about python subprocess library, tried to implement the same idea there. In python 3.9 my implementation worked great! and fast

**1. So I'm asking, what is the difference between python subprocess and Jvm Process**

**2. Is there a way to create a Jvm subprocess like python**

As I read, subprocesses can be created in Jvm too, by calling `.start()` from the same ProcessBuilder, but its still slow.

**Just to make sure, in case of calling just one time it wouldn't have been a problem.
The problem is that I need to call this file 1000 times in 10-20 seconds**

Adding some code here for examples

Kotlin example - I tested a bit, and `waitFor()` function takes a long time, and that's my problem

[image: Kotlin process code]

Python example

[image: Python subprocess code]

Thank for help :)

Edited:
If this is the same, is there any way to optimize Jvm processes execution? any environments changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python Popen function is equivalent to Java `ProcessBuilder.start()` method.

In your above example, you compare the time it takes Jvm for subprocess to **complete** with the time it takes Python for subprocess to **start**.

To compare same things, you should compare:

#### Jvm

```
// Start subprocess
val processHandle = ProcessBuilder("node", "someFile.js").start()
// Wait subprocess to terminate
val returnCode = processHandle.waitFor()
```

to

#### Python

```py
# Start subprocess
val processHandle = subprocess.Popen(["node", "someFile.js")
# Wait subprocess to terminate
val returnCode = processHandle.wait()
```

### EDIT

I've run simple test on my laptop, and I've not seen significant differences in performance between Kotlin and Python. I'll put it here as test basis, even if measures are not done "properly" (through JMH for Kotlin), it gives an idea:

#### Kotlin

So, for Kotlin, I've made the following .kts script:

```
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder;

fun main() {
    var started : Long = 0
    var completed : Long = 0

    for (i in 0 until 1000) {
        
        val start = System.nanoTime()

        val process = ProcessBuilder("ls").start()
        
        started += (System.nanoTime() - start)
        
        process.waitFor()

        completed += (System.nanoTime() - start)
    }

    println("Average time (ms) to start a process: ${started * 1e-9}")
    println("Average time (ms) to complete a started process: ${completed * 1e-9}")
}
```

Once loaded in Kotlin REPL 1.4.21 upon jre 10, I've got following output:

```
Average time (ms) to start a process: 0.667509729
Average time (ms) to complete a started process: 5.042644314
```

#### Python

On Python 3.7.9, the following script:

```py
import subprocess
from time import perf_counter_ns 

started = 0
completed = 0

for i in range(0, 1000):

    start = perf_counter_ns()

    process = subprocess.Popen("ls")

    started += (perf_counter_ns() - start)
    
    process.wait()

    completed += (perf_counter_ns() - start)

print("Average time (ms) to start a process: ", started * 1e-9)
print("Average time (ms) to complete a process: ", completed * 1e-9)
```

outputs:

```
Average time (ms) to start a process:  1.620647841
Average time (ms) to complete a process:  6.208644367000001
```

So, my current thought is that there should not be any big gap of performance between the two methods *once execution context is ready*. So, if you notice big differences, maybe the problem arise due to some code or initialisations besides the subprocess stuff.

At this point, more details (a minimal reproducible example would be the best) are needed to find out a correct answer.

Comment: Ok, I get that I need to add wait for python.
Tried that and python is still much faster than Jvm. Any idea?

Comment: Well, this is really a mystery...
I tried running the same code you ran. 
No doubt your laptop is better than mine :D my python program ran in 9 seconds
But the kotlin ran in 26 seconds... I checked my kotlin version and jdk, the only difference is that im using jdk 15 by openJdk

Comment: I've got similar results to yours, but that is not explained by the program itself. if I launch the Kotlin example in script mode, It takes 2 times longer than Python (~ 13 seconds vs  ~6 seconds). However, when pre-compiled, time drops to ~ 5 seconds, similar to Python. The extra-time is not spent by the program itself, but by the huge overhead caused by Kotlin/Java big machinery needed to init application context (compile, JIT, Gc, etc.). They perform very poor in that domain, and that's why JVM is often used for long-running services, not for short-lived applications.

Comment: You answered me a perfect answer!
The only thing left that I do not understand is what do you mean by pre-compiled? When I'm running a Jvm program in IntelliJ or other IDE, it should compile it. Or by pre-compile you mean jar file?
Thanks again for the answer :)

Comment: By script I mean using [kotlinc to directly execute source code](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html#using-the-command-line-to-run-scripts) (.kts file): `kotlinc -script sourceCode.kts`. Pre-compile is as you say: first I compile source code in a jar file first, then i measure only execution time of the jar: `kotlin -classpath bytecode.jar MyMainClass`.